# The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListStudentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ListStudentPage();
  }
}

class _ListStudentPage extends State<ListStudentPage> {
  final Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> productsStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Categories')
          .doc('Pharmacy')
          .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: productsStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print('Something went Wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          final List productDocs = [];
          snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map a = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            productDocs.add(a);
            a['id'] = document.id;
          }).toList();
        });
  }
}
```

I am getting this error "The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>" in the line right below( snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document,docs here is highlighted with a red underline)
) , where I created an empty list , can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error and how can I fix it .

Comment: [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) has no such property.

Comment: So how do I fix this , do i need to replace DocumentSnapshot with something else ?

Comment: It's not a [query](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html), it's a document snapshot. You can access the document data by the calling the `.data()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `productsStream` refers to a single document named `Pharmacy` under the `Category` collection. Since you're reading only a single document, there is no need for the `snapshot.data!.docs.map` and you can just return a single widget for the one document you loaded.

Something like this for example:

```
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: productsStream,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        print('Something went Wrong');
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      return Text(snapshot.data!.get('id')); // 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` , because its used when your getting a stream or a list which is the case for you now, while use `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` when your getting a single item.